# Load image using URL into TextView

Tags: android, image, url, download

I am trying to download image using url and set it as TextView background.

```
    Bitmap bmImg;
URL myfileurl =null;
try{
    myfileurl= new URL("https://www.vegetables.co.nz/assets/vegetables/_resampled/FillWyI0MDAiLCIzMDAiXQ/carrots.png");
}
catch (MalformedURLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try{
    HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myfileurl.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    conn.connect();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);
    Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(bmImg);
    tv.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
    tv.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
}
catch(IOException e){
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(PhotoRating.this, "Connection Problem. Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I getting error -->

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.tododatabinding.mock, PID:
>   20288
>                     android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                         at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
>                         at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
>                         at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
>                         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:209)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:163)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:105)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:489)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:465)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:371)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:130)
>                         at com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.productlist.ProductlistFragment$2.getView(ProductlistFragment.java:200)
>                         at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3170)
>                         at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1104)

I have provided `INTERNET Permission` in `Manifest.xml` file. I don't know what the error is.

Option 2:

I have also tried `Picasso` , adding dependency `compile com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0` to app/build.gradle

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Picasso.with(this)                        .load("https://www.vegetables.co.nz/assets/vegetables/_resampled/FillWyI0MDAiLCIzMDAiXQ/carrots.png").into(tv);
```

It shows

```
cannot find symbol variable Picasso
```

Comment: You are calling network call on main thread use AsyncTask to do the same

Comment: You Should not do network tasks on main UI thread. Always use async task class or a handler to do it. That's why your app is crashing.

Comment: It's advisable to leave such tasks to libraries like `Glide` or `Picasso`. You can rely on them to do the heavy lifting like multithreading, fetching, decoding, and displaying.

Comment: thank you all, it worked with using   async task class . thanks @Umair

Comment: But it is taking little time load images

Comment: @SanDaniel it will take some time. If you want to skip it use picasso/glide to render image quickly. Happy coding :)

Comment: Will anybody tell how to store and retrieve bitmap images in android  using SQLite database ?